# What is the best plugin for code analysis in groovy?

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

I am using Grails 2.0.3 as platform and Netbeans 7.1 as an IDE. Which of the available plugins for code analysis in groovy works best? Codenarc and GMetrics are on my list.

Anyone who have tried these? Which one is better?

Comment: I have used codenarc and it does the job very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeNarc and GMetrics both analyze different things. CodeNarc checks code for style, best practices and other inconsistencies. GMetrics analyzes the complexity of your code and will tell you the cyclomatic complexity and line counts and whatnot.

If I was only going to use one of these plugins, I would use CodeNarc because it helps train you to follow best practices in your code and will improve your code quality. However, there is no reason why you shouldn't or can't use both.

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea! I'll be using CodeNarc :)

Comment: I can't find any blog explaining how to use either of them in eclipse with maven. Can anyone help?